# While running Firebase init I got error in Deploy setup using Github

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I am new to Firebase and when I use Firebase init --debug I got the following error in Deploy setup using github

Deploy Setup
? How do you want to deploy Deploy using github
[2023-11-16T17:26:59.036Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET [https://placeholder.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/%5C\[object](https://placeholder.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/%5C%5C%5Bobject) Object]/locations/us-central1/backends/acme-inc-web [none]
[2023-11-16T17:26:59.268Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET [https://placeholder.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/%5C\[object](https://placeholder.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/%5C%5C%5Bobject) Object]/locations/us-central1/backends/acme-inc-web 404
[2023-11-16T17:26:59.269Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET [https://placeholder.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/%5C\[object](https://placeholder.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/%5C%5C%5Bobject) Object]/locations/us-central1/backends/acme-inc-web "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">\n  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  </style>\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>\n  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1alpha/projects/[object%20Object]/locations/us-central1/backends/acme-inc-web</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>\n"

Error: Failed to get or create a backend using the given initialization details: FirebaseError: Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON